# Encoding.ASCII.GetString() Problem VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, encoding, network-programming

i got a problem when receiving data from networkstream that was converted from bytes to string.. the output would be the same but when i compare the the string generated from Encoding.ASCII.GetString() compared to the actual string, the output is not the same..

this is my code..

Server:

```
Dim tcp As New TcpClient
tcp = findTCP(ip)
Dim ns As NetworkStream = tcp.GetStream
Dim b As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("a")
ns.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
Dim bb(tcp.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
ns.Read(bb, 0, tcp.ReceiveBufferSize)
If Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb) = "b" Then
    a = "conn"
Else
    a = "not"
End If
```

Client:

```
Dim ns As NetworkStream = socClient.GetStream
Dim b(socClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
ns.Read(b, 0, socClient.ReceiveBufferSize)

Dim bb As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("b")
ns.Write(bb, 0, bb.Length)
```

just for ping purposes.. :)

my server pings to client..

is there any instance that when the string will be converted to bytes, the string will change? :?

Comment: Have you debugged the application to see what the actual values of the byte arrays / strings are? The string won't change by converting it to bytes and back again.

Comment: mmm.. what im doing is msgbox Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb)  <-- output: b    |||||||||    If Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb) = "b" Then
            a = "conn"
       suppose to be..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of the `Read` method, which would tell you how many bytes it actually did read. Everything after that in the buffer is garbage. Also it would tell you if you have read all of the stream or not, so you have no idea if you read all the data, or how much data there is.

Use the return value of the `Read` method to determine what you get, and whether you need to call it again. Assuming that an array of 1000 bytes is enough to hold the stream, this should work:

```
Dim bb(999) As Byte
Dim pos As Integer = 0
Dim len As Integer
Do
  len = ns.Read(bb, pos, bb.Length - pos)
  pos += len
Loop While len > 0
```

You also need to use that length when you decode the data, or you will decode the entire buffer, including the garbage after the actual data:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb, 0, len)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your byte arrays are declared far too large. This causes the strings to have extra appended characters which would mess with your string comparison logic.

ReceivedBufferSize is the buffer size internally in the socket and will usually have a value ranging from 2.000-8000 bytes. You should instead use the Available property which indicates how many bytes that are currently received.

```
Dim bb(tcp.Available) As Byte
```

Comment: i changed it to Dim bb(10024) As Byte but still not the same string

Comment: Try changing it to Dim bb(tcp.ReceiveBufferSize - 1) As Byte

Comment: still not the same.. i even tried using trim.. anyway, how can i see the whole data in byte array..

Comment: Set a break point on the line, and then hover over the array variable.

Comment: My bad, you shouldn't use ReceiveBufferSize but Available.